# string split for an entire column

Tags: r

The code below produces the vector for the 1st element of a column of data (ncv.gender$`Identity Number`). The result is shown. 
What code is required to display the result of every element in the column?

```
ID <- as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(ncv.gender$`Identity Number`), "")[[1]])
ID
#[1] 9 4 1 2 0 7 0 6 0 4 0 8 5
```

Thank you

Comment: ```lapply(strsplit(as.character(ncv.gender$`Identity Number`), ""), as.numeric)```

Comment: Thank you (Baie, baie dankie.)